# Problem with the Display after moving hard drive from one laptop to another

Tags: xorg

I am having a problem with the Display on my Laptop running Ubuntu 10.04

Since last few days, I am using the laptop in low-graphics mode. When I try to run the command `glxinfo`, I get a error message

> xlib extension glx missing on display !:1.0

and causes a Segmentation Fault.

I am using Toshiba Laptop with 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller ( Output from `lshw` )

Note :

I was using Sony Laptop with NVIDIA Graphics card. I took the HDD from Sony Laptop and put it in Toshiba Laptop having Intel Chipset Graphics Card.

Since then, I am having the problem with the display.

I tried to remove the drivers from NVIDIA but with no success.

Please let me know, how to remove the NVIDIA drivers completely and install Intel Drivers.

Comment: How did you install the NVIDIA drivers in the first place?  Did you use the proprietary driver tool in Ubuntu (System->Administration->Drivers -- I think [my Ubuntu boxes aren't here]), or did you download and build the source from NVIDIA?

Comment: I didnot install NVIDIA Graphics Driver. I installed the drivers with the OS installation (On a Sony Laptop). Now I am using the Old Ubuntu installation from the HDD on a Toshiba Laptop with Intel chipset graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`.  This should cause X to reconfigure itself.  The appropriate driver (i915) should get automatically chosen.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.. :) It worked, I installed some applications and removed many from "Ubuntu Software Center". I am not sure, what tricked and what made the Xserver to reconfigure. When I reboot the system, after the many installation and uninstallation, there I had the system, which I always wanted with the xserver properly configured. Thanks again for your time..

Answer (score -1):

The driver should have an uninstall switch like so:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA* --uninstall
```

Comment: Does this command work ? It doesnt worked me. I got a error message cannot open "sh: Cant open NVIDIA*"

Is it possible to uninstall through apt-get remove command ?